# Is there a limit on how many different apps can single developer publish on Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I did the googling and checked all the relevant questions on StackOverflow but question is still standing:

**Is there a limit on how many different apps can single developer publish on Android Market?**

I am not talking about updates etc. I mean different Free Applications with different ID, different functionality and different APKs under same developer ID.

Proof links are more than welcome.

**Update:** I am aware of the limit on size. But the question is there a limit on amount?
Failed to find anything on it in Terms of Service but I am not a lawyer.

Thanks.

Comment: limit on size is there, but why limit on number of apps per developer? why would google do that? doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637864/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-updates-on-single-apk-to-publish-or-upload-on-andro?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated 2021**

After conversing with Google Play Console customer support, the answer is that there is no max limit on the number of apps you can have. The only limit is of uploading a maximum of 15 **new** apps per day. Quoting the conversation:

**Ques**:

> Is there a limit to number of apps per account or the number of app updates per day per account? The only limit I could find in documentation was for private apps within a organization. The [Manage private Android apps in Google Play](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanaging-private-apps-in-admin-console-versus-google-play-console%2Cimportant-information-about-app-publishing) document mentions : `You can upload up to 15 private apps per day.` However, it talks nothing about the public apps.

**Ans**:

> The current upload limit for apps on the Play Console is 15 apps within a 24 hour period.
> This limit includes the first APK uploaded for an app project, even if those projects that are deleted later on. The 15 app limit does not include APK updates for existing apps.
> To upload another APK to an app project for the first time, you'll need to wait 24 hours after you uploaded your last APK. To prevent reaching this limit in the future, I recommend updating an app instead of deleting and recreating a project.

**Ques**:

> Is there a document that I can refer to which states the limit?

**Ans**:

> Unfortunately, there isn't at the moment.

Answer (score 20):

Judging by the lack of "any" documentation that would stipulate these regulations, I'd have to say NO. There is no limit to the number of apps per developer ID that can be uploaded, simply size constraints per apk. Why would the Android team try to limit the amount applications uploaded by any developer?

**For instance:** If I were to create 5 really bad apps, and they had a cap of 5, I would then not be able to take my experience programming those bad apps to create my final "well rounded" application. Thus they would be allowing me to put 5 bad apps and not the good ones, and in essence bringing the overall quality of their market WAY DOWN. That's just a simple example of why I don't think this would ever happen.

Another would be that there are people, or companies, that can code 15-20 good apps that would benefit the Android Market. If they limit them to a certain number, then they're shooting themselves in the foot again..

Comment: @BorisDaich: Yeah, but they could very easily look into special cases (devs with over 10 apks??) and deal with them if they're abusing, rather than simply limiting the number of apks that any one dev can publish...

Comment: Ok then i guess the question is what number starts to be "special case" that google look in to and evaluate if it is abuse?

Comment: @Boris: I'm unable to answer that, you'd have to probably request this information from somebody at Google because I can't find a single reference to this on my end. Sorry..

Comment: I have the limit to upload 15 apk files per day.

Comment: @Dimmduh Why are you limited to 15 apk file uploads per day?  Do you have a link to any documentation from Google that outlines this policy?

Comment: Better question might be why are you uploading more than 15apk per day?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I thought I would comment on the "15 per day" limit. I cannot find it documented anywhere, but when I wrote Google Play support on the issue, that is the number that was given to me by the person who answered my request. The limit does not apply to updates, but only to the first APK uploaded for an app project.

Answer (score 16):

Google publisher account have a limit of 15 APKs per day. and there is no limit on number of apps by developer. i have uploaded more than hundred apps in my account and it is still active .

Comment: Updating an APK also counts. So if you update the same APK 15 times, you've reached your limit.

Comment: tell me few apps name which you have published.

Comment: Well, a hundred is quite much huh

Answer (score 3):

I have an old suspended account from 2012 had over 2500 apps published, but with new policies coming out Google forced us to update all apps in 30 days, impossible to update that many in a month so my account got terminated even though I unpublished the apps I didn't update. I also had a friend that had over 5000 live wallpapers on his account.