# Maximum number of apk upload/day

Tags: android, google-play

Any one know the limit of apk upload per day? How many times I can update an appln apk in playstore for a day? Recently I came about this thought. Can any one help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how many different apps can single developer publish on Android Market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152002/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-different-apps-can-single-developer-publish-on-andr)

Comment: @Rohith: I meaned about updating for same application , the allowed number for a day. I sow the question, but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a limit on how many different apps can single developer publish on Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152002/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-different-apps-can-single-developer-publish-on-andr)

This is the question mentioned by @Rohit in their comment. There is no documentation which leads to the belief that there is no maximum upload cap, though one user has stated they are capped at 15 uploads, but it isn't clear why....

Unfortunately you've hit a bit of an information void, and I think the only solution would be to try and contact the play store team themselves to ask.

Comment: Google stopped me to upload apk after 15 apks's in a day.

Comment: when is the day end ?