# Upload new APK to production - Failed

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am getting this error while trying to upload new `APK` to `Google Play`.

[image]

Any **official** limitation about the amount of time I can upload new `APK`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many apps did you upload?

Comment: 7 days limit I guess

Comment: @JörnBuitink Don't really remember, ~20

Comment: Read https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65759

Comment: And can be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988781/maximum-number-of-apk-upload-day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on how many different apps can single developer publish on Android Market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152002/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-different-apps-can-single-developer-publish-on-andr)

Answer (score 2):

It is a known limitation. You can upload about 15 APK in 24 hours:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65759

Comment: I google as well m8, and it's not official by google, Where can I see this official limitation?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an official statement. As explained also by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9152222/2837959) answer the limit is 15.