# Is there a limit on how many updates on single apk to publish or upload on Android Market (Google Play Store)?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-developer-api

I did the googling and checked all the relevant questions on StackOverflow but question is still standing:

Is there a limit on how many updateson single apk publish on Android Market?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can upload a max of **15 apks** in a day to the andriod play store (including new apps or updates on same or different apps). To continue uploading more you have to return after 24 hours of the last upload timestamp.

Here is what you'll see when trying to upload the 16th apk.

[image]

#### UPDATE:

Recently noticed that the restriction of 15 apks on app updates is not there anymore but it continues for new app additions.

Comment: Can you reference the documentation which would specify this restriction please?

Comment: I have 300 apps and have to go through this pain over 20 days when updating apps EVERY TIME :(

Comment: Unfortunately there is no document stating this. I myself looked a lot when i first saw the error. Try going more than 15 and you'll see it for yourself.

Comment: found an image showing the error message. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks  AndroidMechanic

Comment: Thank you! , I needed it

Comment: Is this still true in 2020?

Comment: @YahyaUddin For 2021 update regarding this question, checkout the new answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67208264/1306419. It includes the conversation I had with the Google Play Console customer support.